# Black screen during Ubuntu installation 1

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on an Acer Aspire A315-41-ROLT. I have unpacked the .iso file to my flash drive and booted to GRUB successfully, but when I select "Try Ubuntu", I just get a black screen and that's all. I have also tried to select "Install Ubuntu", but I get many errors.

Can you give a solution please?

Comment: Acer does not provide support for Linux, nor does it provide Linux device drivers: https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/support-product/7540?b=1  Therefore, to help us help you, please disable Secure Boot and Fast Boot in your BIOS/firmware setup, and try again. Please click [edit] to report whether that worked, or not.

Comment: Allo, thanks you for your answer. I will try this method and see how it's going !